# which regression model to choose

Tags: regression

I have a variable showing "how long time takes to stand up from a chair 5 times in a row as quickly as possible" as response (measured in second) and a binary variable showing cancer or not as covariate. I want to know which regression is correct to be used for this case.

[image]

Comment: What regression models do you have in mind, and what do you want to learn from your data? // Your problem is simple enough that just graphing the two data sets (time for diseased subjects, time for non-diseases subjects) in different colors is easy and likely to reveal a great deal.

Comment: How do you know the disease is an all-or-nothing disease vs. using a measure of _extent_ of disease?

Comment: @FrankHarrell please see the update. the covariate is a binary variable cancer or not.

Comment: @Dave please see the update. the covariate is a binary variable cancer or not. Which regression i should use. I want to see the risk of cancer or not in my reponse variable and adjust for age, gender.

Comment: Cancer doesn't really exist that way.  It depends on how long ago the cancer started, size of tumor, effect on physical functioning, etc.  For your question I'd suggest the Wilcoxon test or the Cox proportional hazards model.

Comment: @Frank Harrell
this is really a great suggestion, but if only assessing this in one time point. except the cox model which model is better? wilcoxon test is good , but I cannot adjust for age, gender, ...

Comment: @Frank Harrell I have updated the question with the histogram of the outcome.

Comment: The Wilcoxon test generalized to the proportional odds ordinal logistic regression model, allowing for those covariates to be included.

Comment: @Dave I am not sure if I understand correctly, please see the histogram of the outcome in question.

Comment: The histogram has too few bins to tell us a lot about the raw data, but doesn't really affect the choice of tests / regression models.

Comment: The t-test is a simple linear regression than can be extended to involve covariates (e.g., ANCOVA). In this same way, the Wilcoxon test is a simple proportional odds ordinal logistic regression.

Comment: @Dave linear model maybe is better. I am not sure why you suggest ordinal logistic regression as my response is not either category r nor binary.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking at the time-to-event of interest, I'd go with Cox Proportional Hazards Regression. In this way, you could check if your covariate has an influence not only in number of events but, also time to events.

I'd also check Kaplan-Meier curves to display the data (since it plots time-to-event).

Answer (score 0):

My first idea would be logistic regression with x=time and y=0/1 (no/yes cancer), but I wouldn't expect a phantastic result since so many other factors can play a role here.